# Get Lightning Platform Actions by Apex code

Tags: apex, page-layout, global-actions

Is this possible to retrieve list and metadata of Lightning Platform Actions by Apex code?
I know that this is possible to get using Metadata API but I am looking for a native Apex way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [`Metadata.Operations.retrieve` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm#apex_Metadata_Operations_methods) and [PlatformActionListItem class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_PlatformActionListItem.htm#apex_Metadata_PlatformActionListItem_properties) like following to get list of platform action included in given layout:

```
Metadata.layout layout =  new Metadata.layout();
List<String> layoutList = new List<String>{'Test_Object__c-Test Object Layout'};

List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, layoutList);
layout = (Metadata.layout)components.get(0);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + JSON.serialize( layout ) );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + layout.platformActionList.platformActionListItems[0] );
```

---

Also, another way to get list of actions is to call `QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Account')` - this method would return all actions (both platform and quick actions for Account, or `QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Global')` - this method would return list of all actions (both platform and quick actions)

```
 Object v  =  
    JSON.serialize( QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Account'));  

// Called at global level, not entity level.
List<QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult> result2 = 
    QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Global'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + v );
 System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ result2: ' + result2 );
```